ACPI BIOS Error During Boot: Could Not Resolve Symbols
During boot, my Linux system displays the following error messages:

[  0.129513][ T1] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCO0.1200.TPDO], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswload2-162)
[  0.129521][ T1] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
[  0.129543][ T1] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCO0.1200.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswload2-162)
[  0.129546][ T1] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)

These error messages seem to be related to the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) BIOS implementation on my system.

Question 1: What is the cause of this ACPI BIOS error during boot?
Question 2: How can I resolve this issue and successfully boot my Linux system without encountering the ACPI BIOS error?
Question 3: What are the potential consequences or limitations of the workarounds or solutions suggested for this problem?
Question 4: Are there any specific hardware configurations or system setups that are more prone to this type of ACPI BIOS error?
Question 5: Is there a way to identify the root cause of the ACPI BIOS issue, such as a specific hardware component or BIOS implementation, to help troubleshoot the problem more effectively?

Please provide a detailed explanation of the ACPI BIOS error, its potential causes, and step-by-step solutions or workarounds to resolve the issue, taking into account the potential trade-offs or limitations of each approach.

A bit of Googling indicates the symbols _SB.PC00.I2C0.TPD0 and _SB.PC00.I2C0.TPL1 might refer to a I2C-bus-based trackpad and a touchscreen, respectively. If your system does not have those hardware elements, the errors indicate the ACPI firmware implementor has not "cleanly" disabled the ACPI code for them, but instead just deleted the definitions and let any remaining references to them become errors. The timestamps at the beginning of lines indicate these errors are all generated within ~0.13 seconds of kernel startup, so they cannot be the cause of any significant boot delay.

Thank you for the detailed analysis and explanation regarding those ACPI error messages during boot. I really appreciate you taking the time to research the root cause behind those "_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPD0" and "_SB.PC00.I2C0.TPL1" errors.
You're correct that my system does have a trackpad, but it does not have a touchscreen. Your insight that the ACPI firmware implementation is not properly handling the absence of the touchscreen device by just deleting the definition instead of gracefully disabling it makes complete sense for why I'm seeing that particular error. @telcoM

I'm relieved to know that despite their alarming appearance, these errors are generated so early in the boot process that they cannot be responsible for any significant boot delays I may be experiencing. Knowing they are more of a cosmetic issue stemming from the ACPI firmware's lack of graceful handling for missing hardware helps narrow down my troubleshooting efforts. @telcoM


Question 1: What is the cause of this ACPI BIOS error during boot?

As the error message says, this is a bug in your firmware. This isn't a new problem, somewhen in the 5.x kernel release cycle these things started to be logged.
I assume your boot works (otherwise you'd have told us in your question that it doesn't).

Question 2: How can I resolve this issue and successfully boot my Linux system without encountering the ACPI BIOS error?

Probably not at all, unless you happen to be the mainboard firmware contractor :)
You should try updating your motherboard firmware, though, and using a modern Linux kernel. You haven't told us yours, but I believe the way this is printed is specific to (relatively old by now) kernels < 5.14(??). Try booting from a USB thumb drive, maybe with the current Fedora live image, and see whether the errors are still the same.

Question 3: What are the potential consequences or limitations of the workarounds or solutions suggested for this problem?

None, really. Linux works around these pretty gracefully all by itself, or things just won't work. Unless you're encountering problems related to ACPI, I'd ignore all this.
Switching off ACPI on anything modern is probably a cure worse than the disease, so let's not consider that.

Question 4: Are there any specific hardware configurations or system setups that are more prone to this type of ACPI BIOS error?

Yes. Some vendors take more care when implementing ACPI tables than others.
That won't help you; these are mainly name-brand server manufacturers, and even among these there's differences.

Question 5: Is there a way to identify the root cause of the ACPI BIOS issue, such as a specific hardware component or BIOS implementation, to help troubleshoot the problem more effectively?

The error message (I think) is already pretty descriptive: The ACPI table is incorrect. The people building your motherboard or your CPU (whichever is really at fault here) probably knew that and shipped it anyways. Happens all the time, price- and time-pressure makes them not care about this (Windows and Linux still boot – what's the business case for fixing it then?). This will probably never be fixed. But let's face it, this isn't really a problem, either. (unless you forgo to tell us a real problem!)

Thank you very much for your clarification!
Yes my boot works fine and you guessed correct ;)
Here are some new infos:
OS: openSUSE Tumbleweed x86_64 /
Kernel: 6.8.5-1-default /
DE: Plasma 6.0.3 /
Host: Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IHU6 /
I tried multiple OSs Arch, Mint, Ubuntu, and now Tumbleweed; All of them have the same problem!
And my real problem is in boot performance! I should have a boot time between 2 to 6 seconds with this system! not 10 to 15 seconds!!!

that's very unlikely to be related to your ACPI tables. Why do you think your boot should be done after 6s and not 10 or 15? That's not you know a natural law.

Considering my system specifications, it's worth noting that on Windows 11, I previously experienced a rapid 5-second boot load time. How can I make it faster? Because this ACPI error got me lots of time.

Windows 10 and 11 have the Fast Startup feature, which saves the system state of a freshly-booted system sort of like a hibernation image, and just loads that on subsequent startups instead of starting up all subsystems one by one. If you are comparing a full Linux startup to that, you are comparing apples to oranges.

Thanks for the insightful explanation about the Windows Fast Startup feature. I appreciate you taking the time to clarify the differences between a full Linux boot process and how Windows handles subsequent startups after the initial boot. Your feedback helps provide better context around making fair comparisons across different operating systems' boot mechanisms

@Dr.P you should know that you can hibernate on Linux as well, if you want. (I do have to admit it has given me trouble with my GPU drivers, in the past, though.)

@MarcusMüller Thanks for the tip! I've actually experienced some issues with GPU drivers (and much more) when trying to hibernate on Linux before.
